# Migrate tests from Testim to Selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

We have multiple tests scripts in [Testim](https://www.testim.io/) and after working for an year using Testim it seems Selenium is better suited for the UI automation and looking for available options to migrate Testim Scripts to selenium.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing when re-writing your tests using Selenium:

Comment: Re-writing is not an issue, but we have multiple tests already running in the Testim grid. We want to migrate all the tests from testim to selenium

Comment: Yes, you re-write them using Selenium and shutdown your testim-based ones. What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Searching for any other option apart from re-writing the tests. A migration kind of tool or any SDK based option available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have an option in Testim to export the Test Cases as Selenium Test in JS/TS. This is a Beta feature and has to be done at individual level

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any migration tool available. It should still be easier to start with the Testim exported tests and make some modifications than to start writing from scratch.

I've never seen a Testim customer go back to Selenium. Slow authoring of flaky tests is generally a recipe for slowing down your release cycles. You will more than offset any savings in license fees by increasing your selenium personnel costs.